# JAXb not populating object during unmarshal

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am a bit lost at this point.  I am by no means a SOAP/JAXb expert, however, I am trying to create a generic class that will marshal/call/unmarshal for any service.  I am using the Weather Service wsdl as a starting point to prove out the concept.

I have finally gotten the marshalling, call and unmarshalling to execute without error, however, the response object is not being populated.  Can anyone assist in identifying what I am doing incorrectly?  I am also looking for a good explanation to the answer if possible so I can learn from this experience.

Again, there is no error while excuting.  The issue is that the value of GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse.GetCityWeatherByZIPResult comes out to be null.  I know  the document is returning the correct results as the result printout is as follows:

Result printout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
    <GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
        <Success>true</Success>
        <ResponseText>City Found</ResponseText>
        <State>MO</State>
        <City>Saint Charles</City>
        <WeatherStationCity>Farmington</WeatherStationCity>
        <WeatherID>4</WeatherID>
        <Description>Sunny</Description>
        <Temperature>79</Temperature>
        <RelativeHumidity>47</RelativeHumidity>
        <Wind>CALM</Wind>
        <Pressure>30.00S</Pressure>
        <Visibility/>
        <WindChill/>
        <Remarks/>
    </GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
</GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse>

Response: GetCityWeatherByZIPResult: null
```

Test Web Service:
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx

Initial call (done via JBehave):

```
@Given("I call the weather soap service")
public void givenICallTheWeatherSoapService() {
    GetCityWeatherByZIP weather = new GetCityWeatherByZIP();
    weather.setZIP("63304");
    try {
        new WeatherTools();
        WeatherSoap weatherSoap = new WeatherSoap();
        GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse response = weatherSoap.getCityWeatherByZip("63304");
        System.out.println("Response: " + response);
    } catch (JAXBException | ParserConfigurationException | SOAPException | IOException e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Soap Service Class:

```
public class WeatherSoap extends PTFSoapClient {

    public WeatherSoap() throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException, SOAPException {
        super(PTFApplication.getConfig(Environment.executionEnv.getEnv(), "Weather SOAP endpoint"));
    }

    public GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse getCityWeatherByZip(String zip) throws JAXBException, SOAPException, IOException {
        GetCityWeatherByZIP weatherByZip = new GetCityWeatherByZIP();
        weatherByZip.setZIP(zip);
        try {
            sendRequest(weatherByZip);
            return (GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse) unmarshallResponse(GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse.class);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Base Framework Class genericizing the call (usable for all SOAP calls):

```
public class PTFSoapClient {
    private JAXBContext context;
    private Marshaller marshaller;
    private Object object;
    private SOAPMessage message;
    private String endpoint;
    private SOAPMessage response;

    public PTFSoapClient(String endpoint) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public void toConsole() throws JAXBException, SOAPException, IOException {
        message.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public SOAPMessage sendRequest(Object obj) throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException, SOAPException {
        object = obj;
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
        marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        marshaller.marshal(object,doc);
        MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        message = factory.createMessage();
        message.getSOAPBody().addDocument(doc);
        message.saveChanges();

        SOAPConnection connection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
        response = connection.call(message, endpoint);
        connection.close();

        try {
            System.out.println("Response:");
            response.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    public Object unmarshallResponse(Class<?> classname) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, SOAPException, IOException {
        Document doc = response.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();
        try {
            System.out.println("Document: ");
            printDocument(doc, System.out);
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(classname).createUnmarshaller();
        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(doc);
    }

    public static void printDocument(Document doc, OutputStream out) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), 
             new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")));
    }
}
```

Base unmarshal object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse",
                namespace = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/")
public class GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse {
    GetCityWeatherByZIPResult GetCityWeatherByZIPResult;

    public GetCityWeatherByZIPResult getGetCityWeatherByZIPResult() {
        return GetCityWeatherByZIPResult;
    }

    public void setGetCityWeatherByZIPResult(GetCityWeatherByZIPResult GetCityWeatherByZIPResult) {
        this.GetCityWeatherByZIPResult = GetCityWeatherByZIPResult;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GetCityWeatherByZIPResult: " + GetCityWeatherByZIPResult;
    }
}
```

Sub umarshal object:

```
public class GetCityWeatherByZIPResult {
    boolean Success;
    String ResponseText;
    String State;
    String City;
    String WeatherStationCity;
    String WeatherID;
    String Description;
    int Temperature;
    int RelativeHumidity;
    String Wind;
    String Pressure;
    String Visibility;
    String WindChill;
    String Remarks;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return Success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        Success = success;
    }

    public String getResponseText() {
        return ResponseText;
    }

    public void setResponseText(String responseText) {
        ResponseText = responseText;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }

    public String getWeatherStationCity() {
        return WeatherStationCity;
    }

    public void setWeatherStationCity(String weatherStationCity) {
        WeatherStationCity = weatherStationCity;
    }

    public String getWeatherID() {
        return WeatherID;
    }

    public void setWeatherID(String weatherID) {
        WeatherID = weatherID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return Temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
        Temperature = temperature;
    }

    public int getRelativeHumidity() {
        return RelativeHumidity;
    }

    public void setRelativeHumidity(int relativeHumidity) {
        RelativeHumidity = relativeHumidity;
    }

    public String getWind() {
        return Wind;
    }

    public void setWind(String wind) {
        Wind = wind;
    }

    public String getPressure() {
        return Pressure;
    }

    public void setPressure(String pressure) {
        Pressure = pressure;
    }

    public String getVisibility() {
        return Visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(String visibility) {
        Visibility = visibility;
    }

    public String getWindChill() {
        return WindChill;
    }

    public void setWindChill(String windChill) {
        WindChill = windChill;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return Remarks;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        Remarks = remarks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your Current Mapping

When you specify the `namespace` property on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation, it only applies to that one element.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse",
                namespace = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/")
public class GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse {
```

### Your XML Document

Your XML document specifies a default namespace.  This means that all elements without another explicit namespace mapping are also part of the `http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/` namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
    <GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
        <Success>true</Success>
```

### The Namespace Fix

You are going to want to specify the namespace mapping at the package level so that it applies to all your element mappings.  This is done using the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation on a speciial class called `package-info`.

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about JAXB and namespace qualification on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

---

## Update

### Default Element Names

The default elements for your properties don't match your XML.  for the property below the expected element name will be `getCityWeatherByZIPResult` so you will need to override the default using the `@XmlElement` annotation.

```
@XmlElement(name="GetCityWeatherByZIPResult")
public GetCityWeatherByZIPResult getGetCityWeatherByZIPResult() {
    return GetCityWeatherByZIPResult;
}
```

### Debugging Tip

When you encounter problems unmarshalling, populate your object model and marshal it to see what the expected XML is based on your current mappings.

Comment: I tried what you indicated and added a package-info.java file to com.pgi.qa.weathertools.domain but I still get the same results.


    @XmlSchema(   
        namespace = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/",   
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)   
    package com.pgi.qa.weathertools.domain;  

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;  
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;

Comment: @Mordimer - I have updated my answer with some information that should help.

Comment: I am getting closer now.  The last tip you mentioned (Default Element Names) actually got the first main class populating.  Now its just the attributes within GetCityWeatherByZipResult that are just default values (nulls, 0, false).  I am wondering if its the same issue there.  I will dig into those now and see if that resolves my issue and will post the results here.

Comment: Yep, adding the @XmlElement lines to all the getters in the sub response object fixed the final part of the issue.  I appreciate the assist and explanation.  Was a very fast and insightful post.